# How to fetch comments from a Drupal article in PHP?

Tags: drupal-7

How to fetch comments from a Drupal article in PHP ? The output is preferably in XML / RSS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/commentrss --> if you want  to use module

or you want to do it programmatically ?

**UPDATE:** 
if you have content type "article".. then you can do the following

1- get all the nid from table {node} where type = "article"

2- get all the comment id && comment title `cid` && `subject` from table {comment} where nid = (your articles nid)

3- the last thing is to get the comment body `comment_body_value` from table {field_data_comment_body} where comment id is one of the comments we get in step 2

**SUMMARY :**

1- comments with out body are stored in table {comment}

2- the body of the comments are stored in table {field_data_comment_body} with field name `comment_body_value`

hop that will help u

Comment: the module is good, but I still want to do it programmatically. My current method is directly fetching data from MySQL database (surprisingly, Drupal database schema is straightforward!)